# Check if field is modified in mongoose's post hook for function findOneAndUpdate

Tags: express, mongoose, middleware

In the controller I'm incrementing a field with findOneAndUpdate. The increment is not necessarily always executed, which depends on whether the condition for a update query has been met.
If the field has been incremented tho, an another model should updated as well. So, I was thinking to use:

```
schema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function(err) {
    pseudo-code:
    if (field is incremented)
      anotherModel.update()
});
```

The problem is that I don't seem to be able to determine if the field has been modified.
Self reference (this) points to a funny object of considerable size, (unlike in e.g. middleware functions for 'save'), so I don't see much other options to determine if field is modified.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument passed to the callback for `findOneAndUpdate`'s [post middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) is the matched document to be updated and not an error as common in the node callback pattern. Within the callback, `this` is the query object returned from the `findOneAndUpdate`.

`schema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function(doc) {...});`

Also note that if you want the updated document rather than original document that matches the query you must specify the `new` option in the query:

`findOneAndUpdate(QUERY, UPDATE, {new: true});`